# Python's zip like function in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have 3 lists. Is there any way to add elements from each list one by one in terraform? Like the following:

```
for a, b, c in UNKNOWN_FUNC([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]):
  ...
  ...
```

The output should be like this:

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

**Note 1**: I have tried `zipmap`, but it doesn't do the job.

**Note 2**: The lists would always be of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You could **construct a helper list** for that and then iterate over it. For example:

```
variable "l1" {
  default = [1, 2, 3]
}

variable "l2" {
  default = [4, 5, 6]
}


variable "l3" {
  default = [7, 8, 9]
}


locals {

  new_list = [ for idx in range(0, 3):
            [ var.l1[idx], var.l2[idx], var.l3[idx] ]
        ]

}
```

And to use it in `for_each`:

```
resource "ddd" "ddd"{
  for_each = {for idx, val in local.new_list: idx => val}

  some_attribute1 = each.value[0]
  some_attribute2 = each.value[1]
  some_attribute3 = each.value[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure I understand what your goal is, but it seems like it involves reorganizing the elements to group them by their indices.

Assuming that all of your lists will always be the same length, you could achieve that with a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html), which is comparable to a list or map comprehension in Python.

```
locals {
  lists = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
  ]

  pivot = [
    for i, v in local.lists[0] : [
      local.lists[0][i],
      local.lists[1][i],
      local.lists[2][i],
    ]
  ]
}
```

This uses the length of the first list as a proxy for the length of all of the lists, and so this would fail if not all of the lists are of the same length.